# chrome.tabs.Tab is undefined from popup.js script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-developer-tools

I was going through the Chrome extension "Getting started guide":

> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

and one section mentions this code

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tabs[0].id,
     {code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "' + color + '";'});
};
```

I am getting an undefined error on `tabs[0].id`. Now the API documentation states that `chrome.tabs.Tab` is accessible but I can't seem to get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get tabs via chrome.tabs.query()?

Comment: I shouldn't need to as it isn't part of the guide. If I guide is wrong, I'm fine with that but I have yet to find any info indicating that it is

Comment: Where is your code being executed? And did you add the `"activeTab"` or `"tabs"` permission to the `manifest.json`?

Comment: The guide is outdated and incorrect. You need to use query as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must query the tabs.

If you want to execute the code in all tabs. You can use this code.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    var message = {foo: bar};
    for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "' + color + '";'
            });
        };
    }
});
```

If you want to execute the code only in the current tab. You can use this code.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
            code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "' + color + '";'
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your manifest file, you'll  need to give relevant permission in the `manifest.json` file as:

`"permissions": ["activeTab"],`

to grant access to the tabs API not given already